# How to fix pandas concat when appending of two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

i am trying to combine two `csv` files with the same structure into one combined `csv` file but when i do so the columns are rearranged in a different order and i am missing data from one of my `csv` files.

I have checked both files to ensure their columns are consistent with one and other but when i execute my code one of my `csv` files (variable b) seems to be missing data in the "Social Care DTOC beds" column. I am also getting this message after executing the code :

"FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default. To accept the future behavior, pass `'sort=True'`. To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass `sort=False`"

```
a=pd.read_csv('https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/04/MSitDT-FEBRUARY-2019-full-extract-for-publication-td5dtd.csv')

b = pd.read_csv('https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/03/MSitDT-JANUARY-2019-full-extract-for-publication-5tsrt.csv')

out_put=pd.concat([a,b])

out_put.to_csv( "result.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I am expecting a csv file with the combined rows in the same column order and without data missing from either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is case mis-matching between column headers... eg. `"Social Care DTOC Beds"`vs `"Social Care DTOC beds"` - notice the lower case 'b' in 'beds'.

Simple fix would be to normalise these column headers, using [`str.title`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) (or [`str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) / [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) if you prefer):

```
a=pd.read_csv('https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/04/MSitDT-FEBRUARY-2019-full-extract-for-publication-td5dtd.csv')

b = pd.read_csv('https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/03/MSitDT-JANUARY-2019-full-extract-for-publication-5tsrt.csv')

a.columns = a.columns.str.title()
b.columns = b.columns.str.title()

out_put = pd.concat([a, b])[a.columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is there any reason as to why the column were rearranged, i understand the missing data since there was a mismatch, but i can't make sense of the rearrangement of the columns.

Comment: Not entirely sure. If `DataFrame` work the same way as python `dict`'s then they are unordered by default (if 'columns' are equivelant to 'keys' respectively). To guarantee the order is maintained, you could use `out_put = pd.concat([a, b])[a.columns]`